# Strange Output when Overlapping Views..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Hi Everyone iam new to android and in my project requirement i need to create two LinearLayouts in same Position and they are animated later in the Java Code,For Testing Purpose initially i inserted image views on those layouts got succesfully after that i removed  image views and Inserted EditTexts on the same layout but strange previous image is showing on one linear layout after executing which is not shown in preview

I tested all the options like cleaning the project ,uninstalling from device and reinstaling iam getting the same problem

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  >
 <Button 
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Animate Now"/>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/image_list_fragment"
    android:layout_width="250dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:background="#FF00FF"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    >
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Please Enter some text here"
        android:singleLine="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#32FFFF"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/image_details_fragment"
    >
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Please Enter some text here"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the output the preview in Eclipse and output in Emulator After running

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your backend java file(activity class) once or paste it here. You might be setting an imageview with that background somewhere at runtime.